# Salesforce REST API for object counts with search

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am using Salesforce's parameterized search API - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_parameterized.htm - to search my SF instance. However, it sometimes runs quite slow and I want to just the counts to begin with. I see there's a record count API - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_record_count.htm - but it doesn't accept search terms.

Is there a way to combine these both ? Should I just use the query and use a SOSL query that would just return the counts ? Any pointers on what that SOSL query would look like ?

Comment: If it's slow, you might want to rethink your approach. One alternative - create these counts via a scheduled job that runs on SF platform, then retrieving them will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

SOSL is not a good choice for counting records matching specific criteria. A SOSL result set [maxes out at 2,000 records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm). Additionally, SOSL results have a latency of up to approximately 15 minutes while indexes are updated, and hence may not be fully up to date at any given time.

Instead, use the [Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) REST API resource to execute a [SOQL query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) using the filters you're interested in on a single object at a time, using the [`COUNT()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) aggregate function in your `SELECT` clause.

Bear in mind that complex criteria and large data volumes, especially in combination, may cause even a `COUNT()` query to time out or execute slowly. The fix is situation-specific but likely to involve careful work tuning your query to use indexed fields and efficient comparisons.